# How To Read Notification Firebase oncreate Action

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using fireBase to recive notifcation and handle it in backgroud and i need to get data on onCreate() Method :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
//how to get notification body here not in onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Messages are handled in `onMessageReceived()`, see the example at the bottom.

Firebase has multiple message types - notification messages and data messages: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    //notification message
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    String body = notification.getBody();

    //data message
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but i need to get the data or  the title displayed in the notification on Background and the only way is to get it in onCreate Method

Comment: No, it's not. You will not receive a Firebase notification in `onCreate()` - simply because the method is called when the Service is created and that's it. It doesn't even have an argument.


See this link - it describes where your notifications are passed depending on the case: https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#receive_and_handle_messages